# Reset spring url. URL gets appended after submitting form twice

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, url

```
<form:form action="register/student.htm" method="post" modelAttribute="registerForm">
.....
</form:form>
```

When I initially submit this form the url is

"loclhost:8080/SpringSchool`/register/`student.htm"

If the submit fails and I submt it again, the new url gets appended and becomes:

"loclhost:8080/SpringSchool`/register/register/`student.htm"

As a result I get 404 error. How can I reset the url so that the url is not appended or just basically make this work?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegisterController {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView registerPage(){

        return new ModelAndView("registerStudent", "registerForm", new Student());
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/student", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView registerStudent(@ModelAttribute("registerForm") final Student student, RedirectAttributes redirectAttr){
            ....
            return new ModelAndView("registerStudent", "registerForm", student);            

    }
```

**view resolver**

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: why is the initial form submit failing?

Comment: when it fails to validate you [should just forward request back](http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/)

Comment: @EngineerDollery if the user already exists it fails plus some other business logic

Comment: @JigarJoshi I tried this, but what do I forward it to. I tried as per the link you provided `return "register"` . Instead of forwaring to "register.htm", this statement forwards to register.jsp which doesn't exist. So I get 404 error

Comment: check your view resolver then, it is probably adding .htm at the end which is not where your Spring Servlet is mapped

Comment: @JigarJoshi I have added the view resolver bean above in my question. Do you think the problem lies in my form's action attribute which is `action="register/student.htm"`

Comment: where is view located relative to `WEB-INF` ? and what is the file name ?

Comment: view is in WEB-INF/jsp and the name of the file is "registerStudent.jsp"

Comment: can you say `return "registerStudent";` while forwarding back to the form, (please mention otherwise I won't see a notification)

Comment: I did that but then I end up with my initial problem where the url gets appended and becomes `loclhost:8080/SpringSchool/register/register/student.htm` register two times in the url, which leads to 404 error

Comment: (please use @ mention) I think Ilya is right you need to change form action to `/SpringSchool/register` and keep rest as we discussed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start URL from '/' then it indicate the root of the context but if you start URL from word -- it means 'from the current path'. Your problem should be resolved if you add '/' to the URL:

```
<form:form action="/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register/student.htm" method="post" modelAttribute="registerForm">
.....
</form:form>
```

Comment: I tried this & it doesn't work. it resets the url to localhost:8080/register/student.htm. It gets rid of the "SpringSchool" from the url upon submit

Comment: You can easily add it: <form:form action="/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register/student.htm" ...

Comment: This worked but I had to remove the "/" in front of teh ${pageContext....}. If I keep the "/" there, the url becomes `http://springschool/register/student.htm`. It gets rid of "localhost:8080. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is because your form action is using a relative path. To fix your problem, you should organize your jsp in a folder and your controller should return views with the corresponding paths.

Move your jsp to:

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/register/registerStudent.jsp
```

Your controller should return the view name:

```
register/registerStudent
```

In your form, change action to:

```
<form:form action="student.htm" method="post" modelAttribute="registerForm">
.....
</form:form>
```

Comment: I won't work because in the first place the following URL will be used: loclhost:8080/SpringSchool/student.htm which is not valid URL

Comment: The form action is relative to the path, not the context. In my post, the path would have been localhost:8080/SpringSchool/register

Comment: Oh, I see. I missed that part. That will work as well.